# AutoFocus is missing on Edittext when scanning from Barcode Scanner

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have an issue, when I scan the barcodes using Teemi Barcode scanner, first barcode is able to scan and focus is missing so that second barcode is not able to populating on the edittext.

My code is as Follows

```
 SlabBarcode.KeyPress += (sender, e) =>
        {
            e.Handled = false;
            if (e.Event.KeyCode == keys.Enter && e.Event.Action == KeyEventActions.Down)
            {
                SubmitSlab();
                SlabBarcode.Text = "";
                SlabBarcode.Focusable = true;
                SlabBarcode.RequestFocus();
                e.Handled = true;
            }
            //e.Handled = true;
        };
```

I also tried with another method and code is

```
 SlabBarcode.EditorAction += (sender, e) =>
        {
            e.Handled = false;
            if (e.Event.KeyCode == keys.Enter && e.Event.Action == KeyEventActions.Down)
            {
               SubmitSlab();
               SlabBarcode.Text = "";
               SlabBarcode.Focusable = true;
               SlabBarcode.RequestFocus();
               e.Handled = true;
            }
            //e.Handled = true;
        };
```

I am working on Xamarin android and the android tablet version is 7.1.1 . so now I would like to get focus after scanning first barcode. through debug, i Understand as KeyEventActions.Down method is running, focus is remaining on edittext. when it comes back again for keyeventactions.Up then edittext focus is missing may be with e.Handled case.

Comment: Have you set imeOptions or something else in axml?

Comment: Actually on android tablet version is 7.1.1 , e.Event.Action == KeyEventActions.Down forces to remove the focus on edittext. I remove that one and now focus remains on edittext.